# Unreal Engine5: ERROR: Windows SDK must be installed in order to build this target

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdk, unreal-engine5

I am trying to make a simple c++ project in unreal engine. I have installed the visual studio 2022. I also installed the window sdk for window 11. I also install the dotnet 3.1 version.
But after all this when I want to open some project and select C++ instead of blueprints unreal engine give me this error.

```
An error occurred while trying to generate project files.

Running D:/Unreal engine/UE_5.0/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool/UnrealBuildTool.exe  -projectfiles -project="C:/Users/alikj/OneDrive/Desktop/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
Log file: C:\Users\alikj\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log_GPF.txt

Some Platforms were skipped due to invalid SDK setup: Win64, Android.
See the log file for detailed information

Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
ERROR: Windows SDK must be installed in order to build this target.
```

I have no idea what should I do, I search Youtube and all the other sites on google.
If some body has answer to that please help me,

I want to safely open the project with C++

Comment: Did you "See the log file for detailed information"?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this it worked for me...
Go to the project folder and remove the intermediate, binaries and build folders.
Then try running the .uproject file.
I hope that works !

Comment: I uninstall the visual studio. Now I am facing the problem while downloading the visual studio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by doing the following:

**Step 1:**
Re-install C++ from visual studio by going to the terminal and paste (This may change with time):

winget install Microsoft.VisualStudio.2022.BuildTools --force --override "--wait --passive --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows11SDK.22000"

**Step 2:**
After completing the re-installation, that initial error should be solved but afterward, if you encounter another error like me where the sdk was an insufficient version, then here is how you fix that...

To fix this, go into "Visual Studio Installer".
Select "MODIFY" -> "INDIVIDUAL COMPONENTS"

Then, install the most recent version of ".NET Framework (Latest version number) SDK".

Hopefully that helps everyone.